# Geometry in exported STEP not read into Dassault products

Tags: catia, step

We have generated some solid geometry in our application using the GBrep.Loft method. Geometry is then exported to a STEP file with WriteSTEP(). When imported into a Dassault product, the solid geometry does not get read in. Other geometry types such as curves or points are successfully read from the same file. After investigating the Catia error report, it seems that the Eyeshot STEP has an unexpected format. Is it possible to change the STEP format used by WriteSTEP()? Seems that it is currently using AP203.

Have tried importing to both CATIA V5 and CAE, without any luck. However, the geometry will read into Femap successfully.

Comment: Please try other CAD systems and if the issue is mostly related to Catia ask Dassault's customer service what's wrong with the STEP file.

Answer (score 0):

at first you should save that file at one of your PC Drive as D or E ( not in your desktop)
second for opening your solid you should open your STEP file then go to part body--> PartDesign Future Recognition-->Automatic Future Recognition or it's manual mode --> then you should choose select where you want to change after opening Step files

Good Luck